# Use cases for two-phase initialization

Tags: c++, oop

I've seen a lot of two-phase initialization used. The justification is to call virtual functions from the secondary constructor. However, I've never, ever, seen any use case in which this was necessary. Are there any?

Comment: Necessary as in inavoidable? Nothing is.

Comment: can you post an example of such two phase initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On platforms where there is no support for exceptions, or the code size increase due to exception handling is unacceptable, two-phase initialization allows you to put activities that might fail in the secondary constructor.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's never unavoidable.

In the worst case, this simply calls for a builder function (which may be selected by runtime mechanisms) returning an optional wrapper around the object.

In C++11, with movable types, there is not even a need for dynamic allocation, simply returning a `boost::optional<T>` is enough.

Of course, it does change from calling a constructor directly to calling a builder function/factory. But I prefer the additional burden to a two-phase initialization any day. **Because I don't get no *partial object* that way!**

Answer (score 0):

One way in which I've seen virtual functions called from a constructor in other languages, which cannot be done in a C++ constructor, is:

```
class AController
{
};

class A
{
private:
    // This is only a raw pointer that never gets freed for simplicity
    // The real code does ensure it gets freed when appropriate
    AController *controller;
protected:
    virtual AController *CreateController()
    {
        return new AController();
    }
public:
    A()
    {
        controller = CreateController();
    }
};

class BController : public AController
{
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    virtual AController *CreateController()
    {
        return new BController();
    }
};
```

`A` is a complex object, with several `Controller`-like subobjects (I've only included one), each of which can be derived from (if appropriate) independently. In C++, the `CreateController`-like functions must be called after the constructors have finished, or no `BController`-like objects will ever be created.

It's possible to avoid requiring explicitly calling `Initialize()` methods, but `Initialize()` methods (called from a helper function that also performs the `new A()`) are one of the simpler ways to go.

Comment: But why would you ever do such a thing?

Comment: @DeadMG if you're writing your thesis for a computer science Ph.D?

Comment: @DeadMG This is done in real code, nothing hypothetical. It's done because the `AController` classes are useful for `A` objects, but also for `A1` objects, `A2` objects, etc. where no inheritance between `A`, `A1` and `A2` is possible or desirable. Moving it all into `A` would cause a lot of code duplication: the same code would also be required in `A1` and `A2`.

Comment: @DeadMG To give some more concrete details, `A` is an user interface object, `AController` is the data access layer. The data access layer may be derived from to alternatively retrieve data from a database, from files, from anything else. The user interface may present the data as a table, as plain text, as chart, as anything else. Concrete derivations of the user interface objects are provided that retrieve data from different sources.

Comment: The original question asked where it's unavoidable.   This one appears as if it would be avoidable using the idiom suggested in the C++ FAQ:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom.html

Comment: @BenC The first idiom in the FAQ is what the question asks to avoid, and the second isn't always possible, and is only possible here for some specific helper classes.

Comment: It would seem to me that your code could be replaced by simply holding both the UI and controller objects in a third class and then creating them dynamically.

Comment: @DeadMG The UI object is the root object because that's what other objects know how to create, how to interact with, and how to free. The UI object is in a separate library from the objects that end up creating and freeing it, and it has no control over how they create and free it.

Comment: O rly? Cause I bet that if you gave it a private constructor but a public factory, you'd exactly be able to control that.

Comment: @DeadMG Correct, I misspoke, the creation is something it has full control over, only the freeing (which is done on the UI object) isn't.